# " 'onSensorChanged' overrides nothing " Fault

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sensors, gyroscope

I'm trying to get values from SensorManager. I copied the code from Android API. But problems occurred. Please look at the code.
I was working on the gyroscope sensor. I wanted to examine gyroscope values and results. I found codes on this website
" https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion#sensors-motion-gyro "

I took error message at  override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?)
It says " 'onSensorChanged' overrides nothing  "

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        }
    
    
        // Create a constant to convert nanoseconds to seconds.
        private val NS2S = 1.0f / 1000000000.0f
        private val deltaRotationVector = FloatArray(4) { 0f }
        private var timestamp: Float = 0f
    
    
    
         override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
            // This timestep's delta rotation to be multiplied by the current rotation
            // after computing it from the gyro sample data.
            if (timestamp != 0f && event != null) {
                val dT = (event.timestamp - timestamp) * NS2S
                // Axis of the rotation sample, not normalized yet.
                var axisX: Float = event.values[0]
                var axisY: Float = event.values[1]
                var axisZ: Float = event.values[2]
    
                // Calculate the angular speed of the sample
                val omegaMagnitude: Float = sqrt(axisX * axisX + axisY * axisY + axisZ * axisZ)
    
                // Normalize the rotation vector if it's big enough to get the axis`enter code here`
                // (that is, EPSILON should represent your maximum allowable margin of error)
                if (omegaMagnitude > EPSILON) {
                    axisX /= omegaMagnitude
                    axisY /= omegaMagnitude
                    axisZ /= omegaMagnitude
                }
    
                // Integrate around this axis with the angular speed by the timestep
                // in order to get a delta rotation from this sample over the timestep
                // We will convert this axis-angle representation of the delta rotation
                // into a quaternion before turning it into the rotation matrix.
    
                val thetaOverTwo: Float = omegaMagnitude * dT / 2.0f
                val sinThetaOverTwo: Float = sin(thetaOverTwo).toFloat()
                val cosThetaOverTwo: Float = cos(thetaOverTwo).toFloat()
    
                deltaRotationVector[0] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisX
                deltaRotationVector[1] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisY
                deltaRotationVector[2] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisZ
                deltaRotationVector[3] = cosThetaOverTwo
    
                Log.d("DENEME", "onSensorChanged: " + axisX)
    
                Log.d("DENEME", "onSensorChanged: " + axisY)
    
                Log.d("DENEME", "onSensorChanged: " + axisZ)
            }
    
            timestamp = event?.timestamp?.toFloat() ?: 0f
            val deltaRotationMatrix = FloatArray(9) { 0f }
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(deltaRotationMatrix, deltaRotationVector);
    
            // User code should concatenate the delta rotation we computed with the current rotation
            // in order to get the updated rotation.
            // rotationCurrent = rotationCurrent * deltaRotationMatrix;
        }
    
        fun onClickDevam(view: View) // click event button to check values
        {      
            val sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
            val sensor: Sensor? = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You haven't told the compiler that your Activity is implementing the interface that `onSensorChanged` is a part of. You should probably add `, SensorEventListener` after `AppCompatActivity()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `override` keyword in Kotlin suggests that the class is inheriting a function from a super class or interface. The Android documentation seems to be missing a pretty important step which is having your activity class implement the `SensorEventListener` interface.

To do this change your `MainActivity` declaration to something like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SensorEventListener {
```

`SensorEventListener` contains the `onSensorChanged` function you're talking about. It will also require you to override an additional function, `onAccuracyChanged`, so you'll need to do this as well (but if you don't really care about accuracy changes you can leave the function's body empty - you just need to override it to satisfy the interface).

Android Studio has a handy shortcut for automatically overriding functions from interfaces which you may find useful: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>